# How do you explode a string without spaces or tabs in php?

Tags: php

example:

> KATCAT

result:

> KAT CAT

Thanks!

Comment: What's the logic , or just explain why you need this ?

Comment: Why is `KATCAT` split there?

Comment: how should the solution decide where to place the spaces? What are the rules?

Comment: str_split() with a length of 3, or a regex if you're at least able to articulate a behaviour/pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your logic is to separate the string by a space every three characters, you could use [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) afterwards.

Here is the solution:

```
<?php
$string = "KATCAT";
$result = implode(" ", str_split($string, 3));

echo $result; // "KAT CAT"
```

Here is another example, with more characters:

```
<?php
$string = "KATCATMA";
$result = implode(" ", str_split($string, 3));

echo $result; // "KAT CAT MA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without spaces or Tab, you can use `str_split function`. In details you can visit [php.net - str-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
<?php

$str = "KATCAT";
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);

print_r($arr2);

?>
```

The output is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => KAT
    [2] => CAT
)
```

If you will use explode function then you must have to specify a delimiter because of a required argument of this function. Here in this [php.net - explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you can check it in detail.

```
<?php
    $str = 'one|two|three|four';

    // positive limit
    print_r(explode('|', $str));
?>

Array
(
    [0] => one
    [2] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

Comment: There could be more other solution like : https://eval.in/863189  but OP not explained properly, so it's hard to answer.

Comment: @user2486 Yes, I completely agree the OP not explained properly and there can be other solutions as well.